# UITableView like look and feel using PhoneGap

Tags: iphone, html, uitableview, cordova

I want to create an app with the standard list view and detail view that we get with  UITableView. 
I am using PhoneGap to create the app. While I am aware that PhoneGap is more of an API to enable native app development using HTML5, etc

How do I create a simple list/detail view and integrate with PhoneGap?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must use some UI like Jquery Mobile, for your case exists this theme:
http://taitems.github.com/iOS-Inspired-jQuery-Mobile-Theme/

There is a lot of UI frameworks over there like: JQ touch, Sencha Touch, Jo,... maybe you want to see those too.

Good Luck!

Comment: any such example with iOS 7 look & feel?

Answer (score 0):

PhoneGap has the option for you to integrate your native component into their library but for the purpose of displaying a simple list/detail view I don't think you need to build native component.

But if you really need it, here is the reference, hope it helps

[How to build native Plugin for PhoneGap](http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/36752779/PhoneGap%20Plugins#HowtoWritePluginsforAllPlatforms)